# controlTextDidEndEditing gets called on NSTableView load

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to add edit cell text functionality to a view based NSTableView. I have a data model which has a `name` property and I am using array of that class as the data source for `myTableView`. To add the edit functionality I have implemented the `controlTextDidEndEditing` method like this-

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)
    {
        guard let newName = (obj.object as? NSTextField)?.stringValue else {
            return
        }

        //Added for debugging purpose
        print(myTableView.selectedRow)

        //Update text value of the array item at selectedRow
        project[myTableView.selectedRow].name = newName
    }
```

The problem here is - as soon as I run my app and `myTableView` gets loaded, `controlTextDidEndEditing` gets fired. Since there is no selection initially, the `print(myTableView.selectedRow)` statement returns `-1`.

I get this exception `Cannot pass a negative value for 'index'` when I try to get currently selected cell text as `selectedRow` is `-1` initially.

Why does this method get called on `NSTableView` load? What is the best way to have edit text functionality in a view based `NSTableView`? What I want to achieve is a way to get notified whenever the editing ends on a row so that I can update my object at the backend. I also tried the `NSNotificationCenter.addObserver` method but faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is Cocoa Bindings. Bind the `value` of the text field to the appropriate key path (`objectValue.name`) of the `Cell View`.

No extra code. All bound properties are in sync with the UI elements.

Comment: I tried Cocoa bindings and found out that they are complex enough for me to implement. I am following the MVVM design pattern as well which might not work well with Cocoa bindings. What I want is a way to get notified whenever the text editing ends so that I can update the object value in my database. The `controlTextDidEndEditing` gets fired on initial load and I do not know why.